# Talend tparserecordset - not able to parse date

Tags: date, talend

I am using talend to retrieve data from Oracle DB. I am using tOracleRow to select the data and I am parsing the resultset using tParseRecordSet component. The result set contains date fields and I am getting error on parsing the date filed. Below is my error.

```
 Exception in component tParseRecordSet_1
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unparseable date: "2000-01-01 00:00:00.0"
   at routines.system.ParserUtils.parseTo_Date(ParserUtils.java:245)
   at data.extract_0_1.Extract.tFileInputExcel_1Process(Extract.java:1821)
   at data.extract_0_1.Extract.tOracleConnection_1Process(Extract.java:417)
   at data.extract_0_1.Extract.runJobInTOS(Extract.java:2427)
  at data.extract_0_1.Extract.main(Extract.java:2292)
```

I tried using date format - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ss.S", but still the error exits. Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to use tOracleInput to select data from DB. You don't need to use tParseRecordSet in this case.
2. In schema for 'Date' type column use "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ss" in Date pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have resolved changed the oracle select transforming the date field in string using to_char